# Save file from web?

Tags: android

how do i save file from a website for example an image?

Comment: Open a connection and download?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to put development in title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Android's included [Apache HTTP Client](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/package-summary.html). Here is [a tutorial](http://www.newtondev.com/2010/07/27/making-http-requests-using-google-android/) on how to use the lib.